# Call CosmosDB ToString method in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I have a LINQ query where I need to use the CosmosDB [ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/tostring) method within a query that is built via LINQ in C#. However I have not been able to figure out how to do this. Simply calling ToString() in the C# LINQ expression on the entity value does not work.

I am trying to do a "contains" search on a number value. I can not change the type, and nor can I add a duplicated field that has the number converted to a string.

Essentially what I need is this (in the where clause):

```
CONTAINS(ToString(root["MyProperty"]), "MySearchValue")
```

My current LINQ query is this (MyProperty is of type long):

```
query.Where(x => x.MyProperty.ToString().Contains("MySearchValue"))
```

But this generates the following SQL:

```
CONTAINS(root["MyProperty"], "MySearchValue")
```

Which does not work since MyProperty is a number, so the Contains method always returns false.

So my question is this: How do I modify my LINQ query to wrap the number value in the ToString() method like in my first code sample above? Or is this even possible currently?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core?

Comment: Using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos 3.28 (although I see that 3.31 is available now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a bugfix for this issue awaiting merge here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/pull/3385  Does this apply to your specific situation?

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the same thing as what I am asking. So it looks like this is an outstanding bug then.